# Как сделать инструкцию в приложении?

Tags: java, android

Как листать картинки, как в перископе в android приложении?

Именно, чтобы с точками внизу было?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется вам как-то необходимо охарактеризовать вопрос, потому что сейчас он звучит: "как сделать всё это чудо?" Я абсолютно согласен с ответом VAndrJ, начните с ViewPager, или используйте готовые библиотеки по другому никак не ответить.

Answer (score 3):

Можете, к примеру, сделать свою реализацию с использованием `ViewPager` и такой индикацией.

Можете взять уже готовую реализацию индикации: [вот одна](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator) и [вот вторая](https://github.com/LuckyJayce/ViewPagerIndicator). Можете поискать другие, их много.